# ThinkPad T410 buttons

Tags: thinkpad

I bought a T410 to use as an Ubuntu laptop for robotics work.
I can't find any info on what the buttons above the trackpad are for, and the online user manuals I've found can only be used in Windows, as part of the help system!

Could someone tell me what the upper buttons are for?

I really can't believe there's no PDF online for a user manual, but after some hours all I've found is a hardware service manual, which doesn't seem to have any clues.
Trial and error tells me what the two lower buttons do, and the red joystick.
A manual would be nice to help with BIOS fiddling, too. Sigh.

Comment: Do you know a third party manual site that works under Ubuntu? All the ones I found insist on downloading and installing something that seems to be for Windows, so I couldn't get to the pdf file in Ubuntu.

Comment: I've tried a few of those, but so far I haven't gotten anything usable. Just now I tried a Google Doc that sent me to LiltMedia, which said it had what I wanted, but in fact made me sign up provide charge card accept "free" trial membership then had no such PDF file after all, then I had to jump through hoops to cancel the trial membership and will need to monitor the charge account forever. Do you know of any that are legitimate, not scams? There are so many scams now it's really hard to find legitimate ones, if there are any in fact.

Comment: Manuallibs seems to have lost its domain--it's now for sale as an ad page with pointers to a bunch of related but scam sites (I think... but can't tell for sure).

Comment: I suspected that, so tried manualibs.com instead. It's a valid domain, but points to the same scam sites. Then I tried https://www.manualslib.com but that is the service manual, which I already had, not the users manual. Thanks for your help! But I still haven't found it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPC6w.png Mouse buttons. Also seems kinda OT here unless they don't work at all, and you want to get them working and/or map them for other purposes/

Comment: Thank you all! That imgur picture was what I needed. Never did find a user manual, just a service manual. Weird. Where should one post when looking for such stuff??

Comment: Things that are *ubuntu* specific go here. This feels more like something for superuser, though I'm not sure how well recieved the question would be there. I have a bias as a long time thinkpad user but the dual input setup is roughly as intuitive as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

The buttons do exactly the same as the buttons below the track pad.

They are located so you can use them easily when you use the red 'joystick' instead of the track pad.

Comment: Thanks! What's the little raised structure in the middle above the track pad?

Comment: @DaveGadgeteer, There's a picture here which may help explain: https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8331/8407242937_2c7c6a0552_z.jpg Above the trackpad, the three buttons are: Mouse right click button, mouse middle click button (pressing this does the same as pressing on the wheel on an ordinary desktop mouse), left button. The little thing in the middle of the keyboard is the trackstick, it's a joystick with which can be used as a mouse.